# JSON is created with filetype as File and not as .JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I was watching a tutorial to learn about Node.js, JSON. When I create a JSON and use filesystem(fs) to create a JSON file after I stringify it. JSON is created with a file type of 'File' and not as 'name.JSON'.

```
const fs = require('fs')

const video = {
title : 'how to get more views',
views : '20',
likes : '5'
}

const videoData = JSON.stringify(video)

fs.writeFileSync('JSONWithFile',videoData)
```

The created JSON file should be 'JSONWithFile.JSON' but the result I get is 'JSONWithFile'

Comment: writefile accepts filename with extension as first argument.
const videoData = JSON.stringify(video) fs.writeFileSync('JSONWithFile.json',videoData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create the file, you have to give it the file extension. `JSONWithFile.json`

```
fs.writeFileSync('JSONWithFile.json',videoData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide extension to filename. File name should be like "**JSONWithFile.json**". Below is updated code.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const video = { title : 'how to get more views', views : '20', likes : '5' }
const videoData = JSON.stringify(video) fs.writeFileSync('JSONWithFile.json',videoData)
```

Comment: Did you find above answer helpful?